# I want to redirect all upper-case url to lower-case and vice versa at vps linux hosting at godaddy approx 300 urls.

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess

I have html website hosted at linux vps hosting at godaddy, while i have transform it from windows to linux, then all the uppercase url is showing 404 page, I want to solve this problem, what to do ?

Comment: Rename the files? You can probably automate that with some `find` magic.

Answer (score 1):

if you can use case insensitive URL than use

.htaccess file

```html
rewriteRule (.)* (.)* [NC,L]
```